# Apply an IOperationInvoker to all operations in the entire application at once

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.5

I want to apply an `IOperationInvoker` to all operations in the entire application. I could do this by adding a behavior to each service, but I'd risk forgetting one.

What is the best way to apply an `IOperationInvoker` to all operations without the possibility of forgetting a service?

The service is IIS-hosted.

Answer (score 1):

In your C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config find commonBehaviors

```
<commonBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior/>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior/>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</commonBehaviors>
```

Add your behavior under serviceBehaviors.